# Rails5 ActiveRecord error: TypeError: can't quote Array

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to check to see if there's a pre-existing Update.

The field is receiving_account_id, and it's looks like

```
["1", "3", "4"]
```

and my query is

```
if Update.where("band_id = ? and fan_id = ? and receiving_account_id = ? and response = ?", "#{@remove_member.band_id}", "#{@remove_member.fan_id}", "#{[@remove_member.receiving_account_id]}", "none").any?
```

i've tried all variations of "#{@remove_member.receiving_account_id}, and i get some version of a malformed array literal.

edit:  if i go

```
[@remove_member.receiving_account_id]
```

in the query, i get the type error.    and if i do

```
receiving_account_id && ARRAY[?]
```

i get

```
receiving_account_id && ARRAY['["1", "3", "4"]']
```

which i believe to mean includes in the array, as if the array includes that array, so doesn't find it.

Comment: Remove quote `ARRAY['["1", "3", "4"]']` -> `ARRAY[["1", "3", "4"]]`

Comment: no, that how Rails/Active record interprets receiving_account_id && ARRAY[?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Survey says...

```
Update.where("receiving_account_id && ARRAY[?]", @remove_member.receiving_account_id).any?
```